# Using PyMC3 Posterior Distribution of linear fit, predict confidence interval of y given X

Tags: python, confidence-interval, pymc3, mcmc

I am new to MCMC as well as `PYMC3`. I know how to fit a line to observed data using `PyMC3` using the given [example](https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/GLM-linear.html). After I run the code and obtain the posteritor distribution for the slope (m) and y-intercept (c) for the fit `y = mx + c`, how can I make a 95% confidence interval prediction for the value of y at for a given value of x?. I know how to do it using bootstrap, but is there a more elegant way of doing it preferably using pymc3?

Thanks.

Comment: By "using bootstrap" do you mean that you are directly using your posterior samples?

Answer (score 0):

The point of MCMC is to draw samples from the posterior distribution for your parameters `p(m, c | X, y)`. Once you have the samples, then you can compute various downstream results (e.g., the mean posterior, posterior predictive, credible intervals etc). So there is no notion of a parameterised distribution (which I think is what you are asking) and the only way to compute credible intervals is to use the samples (which if that is what you mean by bootstrapping then this is correct).

Luckily, as you have samples from the posterior, you can simply use the values for `X` at each sample from your posterior to simulate samples from your posterior predictive. Using `np.percentile` will then allow you to calculate the values you are after. This process seems well documented for pymc3 [here](https://arviz-devs.github.io/arviz/generated/arviz.summary.html#arviz.summary).